# select2 does not render after the page loads completely

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I got this problem with a wordpress plugin I’m working on. I tried using this on a local html page, and it works properly. Now, when I tried on a server with wordpress, I can see that it initializes, but after some miliseconds it gets replaced by the vanilla select menu. I don’t know what could be causing this. What do you fellas think?

**edit:** I'd also like to add that the way I see select2 works is that, once the document is ready, it injects its own select element into the document. This seems to happen in my page, but after the page has finished loading the element is gone.

[image]

The first menu is how it’s looking with select2. That’s fine. The second menu on the picture is how it ends up looking - a normal select element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8J5T.png And this is how the script looks like. Nothing complicated, just need to see it run properly first.

This snippet shows that the code is working properly, however i cannot seem to replicate what is happening on the site.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.country-switcher').select2();

  });
</script>
<span class="widgettitle">SHIP TO:</span>
<div class="wc-price-based-country wc-price-based-country-refresh-area refreshed" data-area="widget" data-id="39ddbdcf9476789f65bca6d5b7cda228" data-options="{&quot;instance&quot;:{&quot;other_countries_text&quot;:&quot;Other countries&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;SHIP TO:&quot;,&quot;remove_other_countries&quot;:&quot;1&quot;},&quot;id&quot;:&quot;wcpbc_country_selector&quot;}">
  <select class="wcpbc-country-switcher country-switcher">
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU" selected="selected">Australia</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, y’all!

Comment: Please edit your question to include actual code instead of an (external) image of some code. Or better yet, create this as a [MCVE question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [a snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Done. I used the same snippets of code I'm using on the site. It's very short. I'm thinking it has to do with the wordpress theme because it works well outside of it.

Comment: If your `select2` library loads correctly, then there's only one thing that can go wrong as per the given details. `select2` stylings are being overthrown by your wordpress theme's stylings.

Comment: If it was the styling then the functionality of Select2 would still be there. Unfortunately that is not the case. Let's say that select2 injects a 'new' <select> html element. Well, after the page loads 100% this element is gone, along with the functionality im looking for. However, I do agree that it must be an issue with wordpress itself and not a code issue. I guess I should delete this question then?